# Do we need to submit app for review after changing it to 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Facebook has made some major changes in their Mobile SDKs. They have release API 2.0 and will continue to support 1.0 till 30 April, 2015. They have asked developer to submit app for reviews whoever need more permissions than `public_profile`, `user_friends` and `email`.

We need `publish` permission and `birthdate` for our app. So do I need to submit app after migrating to 2.0 totally or I can submit for review now?

I tried to search but couldn't find anything related to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting for the login review (for extra permissions), facebook tests your app with the detailed steps and screeshots that you'll provide to them.

So answer is simple, you **cannot** send for review before migrating changes in the app. After you've made the respective changes you'll upload some screenshots and steps to use so that facebook developers can test your app and approve/reject the submission.

Comment: So can I submit for review and still use v1.0 API (friends list) or do I have to migrate to 2.0 (and drop all previous version features) to get FB approval?

Comment: v1.0 should not be used now. They will stop working after March 2015. So you must use v2.0. \

Comment: Does `should not` mean `won't work`? I need to get the list of my friends with their IDs so this is the only possibility. Until March 2015 we'll find another solution, but for now it's enough.

Comment: Yes, it will stop working! And you wont be able to find other solution to this, since facebook has stopped this puporsely. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m) what you can do to get the friends.!